# Esc key event not getting fired in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, events

My Esc key event does not seem to be getting fired.

I have two forms.

In form1 button click event

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
frm2.show();
```

In form 2 I've an event called

```
    private void frm2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
        this.Hide();

    }
```

what is the wrong with this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escape button to close WinForm in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290959/escape-button-to-close-winform-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 5):

If the focus is in a child control, you need to set

```
frm2.KeyPreview = true;
```

to handle key events in the form's event handler.

or in the load event handler or constructor of the form:

```
this.KeyPreview = true;
```

Comment: hi thank you for your quick reply.. but may i know where do i put this? in the form1 or form2 ? actually i put it in form2 page load event like this..

form2 frm2 = new form2();
frm2.keypreview = true;

but still the same result

Comment: @Nagu: If you do that in the load event handler, what you're doing is creating a *new* instance of the form with KeyPreview == true. That's not what you want to do. Put "this.KeyPreview = true;" in the load handler or constructor of the form.

Comment: hey it is woking fine but the thing is when i put debugger then only it is working otherwise it is not working.. what is the logic in this?

Comment: @Nagu: Hard to say. Doesn't do that for me.

Comment: @Nagu: Do you have a CancelButton set for the form? If so, that could be the cause (see Henk's answer)