# Escape button to close Windows Forms form in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have tried the following:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if ((Keys) e.KeyValue == Keys.Escape)
        this.Close();
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Then I tried this:

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnKeyDown(e);
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
        this.Close();
}
```

And still nothing's working.

The KeyPreview on my Windows Forms form properties is set to true... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint in those methods?  Is the event handler even firing?

Comment: Don't name your cancel button like the form property 'CancelButton'. Otherwise it seems that you can't set the CancelButton.

Comment: @SteveDanner, event doesn't get triggered. probably declaration in InitializeComponent() is missing.

Comment: I think that the reason it doesn't work is beacause that other controls inside the form got the focus...

Answer (score 206, accepted):

This will always work, regardless of proper event handler assignment, `KeyPreview`, `CancelButton`, etc:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) {
    if (keyData == Keys.Escape) {
        this.Close();
        return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Comment: -1, using of Form's CancelButton property is the correct way.

Comment: Ugh, the 1980s called, they want their dialog box back.

Comment: You can also return `true` from `ProcessCmdKey` to signal that the key is handled, hence preventing the "ding" noise.

Comment: You can only use a CancelButton property of the form if the form has an actual Button on it (or an IButtonControl interface object).

Comment: What makes this the preferred method over the CancelButton property?

Comment: This option is good. CancelButton requires additional **visible** 'Cancel' button on form. This is redundant render + code + etc

Answer (score 67):

You should just be able to set the Form's `CancelButton` property to your Cancel button and then you won't need any code.

Comment: I did that but it's not fired when I press esc, why?

Comment: This worked great for me.  Much better for small forms.

Comment: Keep in mind that the button you set the `CancelButton` to needs to be visible.

Answer (score 16):

Assuming that you have a "Cancel" button, setting the form's `CancelButton` property (either in the designer or in code) should take care of this automatically. Just place the code to close in the `Click` event of the button.

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer indeed is correct, and I've used that approach several times. Suddenly, it would not work anymore, so I found it strange. Mostly because my breakpoint would not be hit for <kbd>ESC</kbd> key, but it would hit for other keys.

After debugging I found out that one of the controls from my form was overriding `ProcessCmdKey` method, with this code:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    // ...
    if (keyData == (Keys.Escape))
    {
        Close();
        return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

... and this was preventing my form from getting the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key (notice the `return true`). So make sure that no child controls are taking over your input.

Comment: Off the top of my head, not sure if you need to set form KeyPreview to true - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I seem to be encountering this issue with ListView controls on my winform.  I wonder if it is the ListView where you saw the problem too?

Answer (score 3):

You set KeyPreview to true in your form options and then you add the Keypress event to it. In your keypress event you type the following:

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == 27)
    {
        Close();
    }
}
```

`key.Char == 27` is the value of escape in ASCII code.

Comment: This is a good workaround to the issue.  I have a form with ListView controls on it and in that case they seem to swallow the CancelButton (when Esc is pressed). I added this code and it fixed the issue.

Comment: This works, but you need to set `KeyPreview` to true for the form

Answer (score 0):

You need add this to event "KeyUp".

```
    private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also Trigger some other form.

E.g. trigger a Cancel-Button if you edit the Form CancelButton property and set the button Cancel.

In the code you treath the Cancel Button as follows to close the form:

```
    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Abort;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

By Escape button do you mean the Escape key? Judging by your code I think that's what you want. You could also try Application.Exit(), but Close should work. Do you have a worker thread? If a non-background thread is running this could keep the application open.