# How to make a form close when pressing the escape key?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a small form, which comes up when I press a button in a Windows Forms application.

I want to be able to close the form by pressing the escape key. How could I do this? I am not sure of the event to use. form_closing?

Comment: For alternative solution see Hans Passant's answer on this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290959/escape-button-to-close-winform-in-c-sharp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escape button to close Windows Forms form in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290959/escape-button-to-close-windows-forms-form-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 155, accepted):

You can set a property on the form to do this for you if you have a button on the form that closes the form already.

Set the [`CancelButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.cancelbutton.aspx) property of the form to that button.

> Gets or sets the button control that is clicked when the user presses the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

If you don't have a cancel button then you'll need to add a `KeyDown` handler and check for the Esc key in that:

```
private void Form_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

You will also have to set the [`KeyPreview`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx) property to true.

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the form will receive key events before the event is passed to the control that has focus.

However, as Gargo points out in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27925932/59303) this will mean that pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> to abort an edit on a control in the dialog will also have the effect of closing the dialog. To avoid that override the `ProcessDialogKey` method as follows:

```
protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
{
    if (Form.ModifierKeys == Keys.None && keyData == Keys.Escape)
    {
        this.Close();
        return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
}
```

Comment: It's a shame that simply adding a hidden button (visible=true) doesn't work

Comment: From a processing perspective, adding a hidden button for this would be a really dirty solution anyway, since in either case, the form will internally have a key listener to make it function. No need to go making an unnecessary button object just to call the function linked to its Clicked listener.

Comment: @SergeWautier You are right, but kkkppps answer is the solution to that

Comment: Is there a reason why the CancelButton property for the form can't call the FormClosing event, or something similar?

Comment: @SergeWautier you CAN add a button.  Add a button to the form anywhere, set TabStop=False, then in the Load event of the Form, set Button1.Left = -Button1.Width.  This way you cannot see it nor can the user TAB to it.  Also, make sure you set Button1.DisalogResult=DialogResult.Cancel, and the Form.CancelButton=Button1.

Answer (score 40):

The best way i found is to override the "ProcessDialogKey" function. This way canceling an open control is still possible because the function is only called when no other control uses the pressed Key.

This is the same behaviour as setting the CancelButton property. Using the KeyDown Event fires always and thus the form will close even when it should cancel the edit of an open editor.

```
protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
{
    if (Form.ModifierKeys == Keys.None && keyData == Keys.Escape)
    {
        this.Close();
        return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
}
```

Comment: I also found this way the best method because using solutions like setting form's cancel button will send key event to parent forms in case your current form is a child dialog form, but this solution is protecting that mistake by finishing key processes when returning true after form close.

Answer (score 8):

```
Button cancelBTN = new Button();
cancelBTN.Size = new Size(0, 0);
cancelBTN.TabStop = false;
this.Controls.Add(cancelBTN);
this.CancelButton = cancelBTN;
```

Comment: This answer should be the correct answer. The button IS hidden, but the "visible"-property is not "false" and that way it works like a charm. Very nice!

Comment: I dunno.. seems quite "hacky".. like being back in the vb6 days.

Answer (score 7):

If you have a cancel button on your form, you can set the Form.CancelButton property to that button and then pressing escape will effectively 'click the button'.

If you don't have such a button, check out the [Form.KeyPreview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx) property.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Forms actually has a property specifically for the situation where you already have a cancel button, but would like to supplement with the Escape-key functionality.

```
this.CancelButton = yourButton_button;
```

The property as described in it's documentation:

> The cancel button of the form. If this property is set, the button is 'clicked' whenever the user presses the 'ESC' key.

It might be worth noting that there's also `this.AcceptButton` for the 'Enter' key instead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3526775

Comment: I only saw the other answer after I provided mine. Though the referenced answer doesn't mention the `this.AcceptButton`

Answer (score -1):

Paste this code into the "On Key Down" Property of your form, also make sure you set "Key Preview" Property to "Yes".

```
If KeyCode = vbKeyEscape Then DoCmd.Close acForm, "YOUR FORM NAME"
```

Comment: This is VBA code. The question is about c# and winforms.