# Changing KeyCode under KeyDown handler of TextBox

Tags: vb.net, vb6-migration

I have to rewrite some my old code from VB6 to VB.NET and here is some things I don't know what to do.
For example I have to replace some keycodes under keyDown event handler of textbox and I can't do this without help.

Most simple to say, I have workable VB6 code:

```
If KeyCode = vbKeyUp Then
   KeyCode = vbKeyEscape
End If
```

When I try to rewrite this literally:

```
If e.KeyCode = Keys.Up Then
   e.KeyCode = Keys.Escape
End if
```

But this won't go:

> Error 2   Property 'KeyCode' is 'ReadOnly'.

Since I have much of such conversions to do is here any way to achieve this simple?

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to accomplish.  The Escape doesn't do anything useful in a TextBox.  If you are trying to close the dialog then override the form's ProcessCmdKey() method instead.

Comment: Hi Hans, of course, I minimised a code to critical part only. I use Escape for detecting keyCode in my own handler part. This is not important in my question while all code is pretty big to post here just for this question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escape button to close WinForm in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290959/escape-button-to-close-winform-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to simulate this in VB.Net is to do the following.  When you see the `Up` key is pressed cancel the event.  Then send an artificial key event for the `Escape` key.

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnKeyDown(ByVal e As KeyEventArgs)
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Up Then
        e.Handled = True
        SendKeys.Send("ESC")
    Else
        MyBase.OnKeyDown(e)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Jared. Conception of my program is (for example) that in certanin conditions change keycode because handler for this new keycode always commes later in code. Your example call a handler one more time, but I think - not important. I try your recommendation and it works. Thank you very much. Only... how to get rid of beeps on every keypress?

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub txtDUnidades_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtDUnidades.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar = "." Then

        e.KeyChar = "," 
        e.Handled = False
    End If
    End Sub
```