# Enter and Tab sends focus to next textbox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox

I had made a class by inheriting the system textbox shown in following code.

```
Public Class textboxex

Inherits TextBox
Private Sub TextBoxEx_Return(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        SendKeys.Send("{TAB}")
        Me.Text = Me.Text.ToUpper  'To change the text to upper case when it leaves focus.(working fine)
    End If
End Sub
```

Now problem is when I press Tab key, it doesn't enter the if condition.
Probably it would not because I havn't given if condition for tab key.

But I after I changed the if condition by adding e.keycode = keys.Tab and pressing tab key, it won't do the Uppercase of the letters but enter does it fine. The updated code shown below.

```
If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter or e.KeyCode = Keys.Tab Then
        SendKeys.Send("{TAB}")
        Me.Text = Me.Text.ToUpper 'doesn't work when tab is pressed | enter works fine
    End If
```

So this is my problem, help me plox...!!!!!!!

Comment: Why not use the [`LostFocus`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus(v=vs.110).aspx) event instead (at least to do the uppercasing).  Then you just need to worry about moving to the next control upon the Enter keypress.

Comment: ya I can do that...
Wait, I check and answer you..!

Comment: This solution might be pretty different from what you did but.. For `Tab` to the next `TextBox`, you could do it by setting the `TextBox` `TabIndex` to be next to one another (example: 15, 16, 17). Then your `Tab` button will work as you desire. Only for `Enter` `Button` you might need to create an `event`

Comment: not a good Idea, because in many textboxes I put validation.

The problem happens when I done changes as you said @JamesThorpe


1. Before it was working like when I press Enter, it opens the connection and check the data if it is valid or not by changing all the text to upper case..   But now it checks the data in lower case and gives me error.

When I tried to focus other textbox without validating the first, at that time the text inside the textbox changes to upper case...!


And tell me how to get a line feed in this stackoverflow comment box<br> not working here...

Comment: I have set all my tabIndex so TabIndex is not any problem... @Ian

Comment: this question may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12990943/changing-keycode-under-keydown-handler-of-textbox

Comment: Use `PreviewKeyDown` event instead of KeyDown. Worked for me.

Comment: Nope, PreviewkeyDown event not working...!!

Comment: It seems you need to set CharacterCasing to upper case and then override OnKeyDown and handle Enter key.

Comment: **Don't do this!** This is completely broken UI. Read [here](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/uibook/fog0000000249.html), starting from *"When the first version of Juno was written, it had the standard log on dialog that prompted you for a user name and a password."*

Comment: @CodyGray Closing a question as duplicate is really sensitive. While the linked post may help the user to solve the problem but it has some problems, **1)** this question is VB and the linked post is C#  **2)** The accepted answer in the linked post even doesn't compile and contains error in constructor! **3)** The current answer in this post offers a different option  rather than the linked post. Here I used `ProcessCmdKey` and also showed the user how to use `SelectNextControl` which in most cases I see wrong usage.

Comment: @CodyGray When I see an experienced user answered a question, even if I know a duplicate for that answer, I'll never close the question as duplicate. In such cases if I think I should do an action, I'll leave a link to the possible duplicate. It's really a more respectful action which is expected from experienced users like you :) - With regards

Comment: @CodyGray I believe closing this question specially using the linked post is a mistake. I'm really interested to hear from you, it can help us to have better understanding of the case and help us to make the site better. Also it prevents from probable misunderstandings.

Answer (score 1):

**To make <kbd>Enter</kbd> work like <kbd>Tab</kbd>**

You can override `ProcessCmdKey` method and check if the key is <kbd>Enter</kbd> then, send a Tab key or ussing `SelectNextControl`, move focus to next control:

```
Public Class MyTextBox
    Inherits TextBox
    Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, keyData As Keys) _
        As Boolean
        If (keyData = Keys.Enter) Then
            SendKeys.Send("{TAB}")
            'Parent.SelectNextControl(Me, True, True, True, True)
            Return True
        End If
        Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Enter key is not the problem @RezaAghaei.
Please see the question thoroughly....
Tab key should work as Enter key but its not working...

Comment: okie I try @RezaAghaei, I just changed my comment.... and plz tell me how to press get a newline in this **stackoverflow comment textbox**

Comment: Okie your **Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
        Me.CharacterCasing = Windows.Forms.CharacterCasing.Upper
    End Sub** helped me but other is not yet helping... I did validation to textbox such as if I press enter from a textbox, it checks the data in the mssql database but on pressing tab, it just jumps to textbox of next textbox without checking...!

Comment: To perform validation you should use `Validating` event and perform validations there. It's not related to the current problem at all :)

Comment: No No, my validations are different so I wrote every validations of the textbox in the particular sub... ex: a textbox has username validation so written in the sub of the form and a textbox has password validation so written in the sub of the form...
My question is why Tab jumps to textbox and not behave like enter after writing the code to behave as enter??? @RezaAghaei

Comment: Thanx for the charactercasing.upper, It worked fine and I found very useful.. @RezaAghaei

Comment: You are welcome, You **really need** to use validating event :) this way if you press tab or enter, your validation rules will fire. :)

Comment: Good luck and let me the result :)  Here I test it and it Worked as Expected ;)

Comment: I can upvote but my main problem of tab is not solved,  I just got a new way to make upper case which was out of the question,  so I upvote but cant upvote + accept

Comment: Okie, having some work but will take time... Plz be available when you see the reply or reply asap when u get available. :P

Comment: No problem. Here we are trying to solve problems and you should test solutions.

Comment: If you use `MyTextBox` Control and also use `Validating` event, I believe it works completely as expected. You never need to handle `Tab` key, the `Validating` event is the event you need. :)

Comment: I seen many example of validating event but it will not be helpful for me because it does not handles any key events and I have to use enter key in my project. @RezaAghaei
I wish somehow you can view my project so you can get better what I want, if any means possible to see my project than please describe, I need to solve this answer..

Comment: Surely if you create a simple form containing minimal code describing your requirement I'll take a look at your code :) and you can find me using r.aghaei at outlook.com