# How to exit all forms with "esc" key?

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello I am modifying a WinForms program. I would like to make it possible to exit any form pressing Esc key.

I tried to bind event to this method, and it works.

```
private void form_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Escape)
    {
        this.Dispose();
    }
}
```

But I want to apply this event to a lot of forms in my project, what is a smart way to do it avoiding to paste this method and bind it to the event manually for each form?

Comment: Try looking at it here if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290959/escape-button-to-close-windows-forms-form-in-c-sharp

Comment: Inherit the affected forms from a base class that has this method.

Comment: Create a form that will act as a base class that has stuff like this, fields and methods you want every from to have, and have all your forms inherit from the base

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override the `ProcessCommandKey` method of the `Form` base class like that by calling `Close()` instead of `Dispose()` because calling dispose is not a good practice:

```
public partial class EscapableForm
{

  protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
  {
    switch ( keyData )
    {
      case Keys.Escape:
        Close();
        return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
  }

}
```

Overriding the method is here better than using an event since it allows a better design consistency.

So anywhere the user is, no matter the active control, keys are catched and you can manage what you want. You can also add any UX condition like an `AllowClose` conditional variable.

To not repeat the code you can create the custom form class file and replace the standard Form base class used by the Visual STudio Designer in any final form like suggested by @Cid.

Comment: Thank you Oliver. Why this is better design consistency?

Comment: Using events is mainly to add on-the-fly behavior on an object while overriding a base method is to extend a functionnality of a class itself. So an event is more related to add a runtime behavior while overriding is to extend the internal behavior of the class. Since here you want to add a functionality, overriding is the best choice. Doing that you don't annoy the event manager by adding an event method to KeyPress. So the execution of the method is more smooth because part of the internal OO design of the class. Thus you have more control to catch and manage keys flow before events too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a decorator pattern, such as :

```
class CustomForm : Form
{
    public CustomForm()
    {
        // automatically bind a keypress event 
        this.KeyPress += new EventHandler(form_KeyPress);
    }

    private void form_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Escape)
        {
            this.Close(); // Close instead of disposing
        }
    }
}
```

And then, all the forms you'd like to have this behaviour can inherit from `CustomForm` instead of `Form`

Comment: Notice the `+=` sign to `this.KeyPress += new EventHandler(form_KeyPress);`. This **adds** a method to the event

Comment: also add  to constructor  this.KeyPreview  = true;