# Handle Closing Keypress of a Created Form [C#]

Tags: c#

I have a form I create that is a simple prompt. It does great but I'd like to be able to close it via the escape key.

I am unsure of how to do this as I can't reference it.

Here is the code:

```
// Create Prompt
    public static string ShowDialog(string text, string caption, bool LimitLength = false)
    {
        Form prompt = new Form()
        {
            Width = 500,
            Height = 150,
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog,
            Text = caption,
            StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
        };
        Label textLabel = new Label() { Left = 50, Top = 20, Text = text };
        Label charlimit = new Label() { Left = 50, Top = 80, Text = "255" };
        TextBox textBox = new TextBox() { Left = 50, Top = 50, Width = 400 };
        Button confirmation = new Button() { Text = "Ok", Left = 350, Width = 100, Top = 70, DialogResult = DialogResult.OK };

        confirmation.Click += (sender, e) => { if (textBox.Text != "") { prompt.Close(); } };
        textBox.TextChanged += (sender, e) => { charlimit.Text = (255 - textBox.Text.Length).ToString(); };
        prompt.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Prompt_KeyDown);

        prompt.Controls.Add(textBox);
        prompt.Controls.Add(confirmation);
        prompt.Controls.Add(textLabel);
        prompt.AcceptButton = confirmation;

        if (LimitLength)
        {
            prompt.Controls.Add(charlimit);
            textBox.MaxLength = 255;
        } // Adjust for MSG command.

        return prompt.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK ? textBox.Text : "";
    }

    // Prompt Key Handler
    public static void Prompt_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
        {
            // Close the Prompt..
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290959/escape-button-to-close-windows-forms-form-in-c-sharp/2290974

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should add a cancel button for your gui:

```
Button cancel = new Button() { Text = "Cancel", 
                               Left = 350, Width = 100, Top = 100, 
                               DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel };
```

Add it to the collection and set the Form's CancelButton property

```
prompt.Controls.Add(cancel);
prompt.AcceptButton = confirmation;
prompt.CancelButton = cancel;
```